# Unable to install CuPy and PyTorch using pip

Tags: python, cupy

I'm trying to install CuPy and PyTorch to run a package that depends on both.

My CUDA version is 10.1, but the CuPy wheels for 10.1 gives the error message below. The error message for PyTorch install is similar and I can post that later if it's relevant.

I've updated Python to 3.7.4 64-bit and have verified that the version is running. I've confirmed using deviceQuery that my CUDA version is 10.1.

Error Message on CuPy install

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install cupy-cuda101
Collecting cupy-cuda101
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/02/a604bed9e84d0c8f75ca5e3c40aaa1442774830c7be0b0c1c82360d4fbca/cupy_cuda101-6.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting fastrlock>=0.3 (from cupy-cuda101)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/ff/6777b85fdbc6efd572a2b713e044c29f5f01ca8b1c74f8d94b427bac60c3/fastrlock-0.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages (from cupy-cuda101) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages (from cupy-cuda101) (1.16.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: fastrlock
  Building wheel for fastrlock (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BRADLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fjh34iu0\\fastrlock\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gemt221d' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: building without Cython
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
  copying fastrlock\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
  copying fastrlock\rlock.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
  copying fastrlock\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
  copying fastrlock\_lock.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
  running build_ext
  building 'fastrlock.rlock' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\fastrlock
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include" /Tcfastrlock\rlock.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\fastrlock\rlock.obj
  rlock.c
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastrlock
  Running setup.py clean for fastrlock
Failed to build fastrlock
Installing collected packages: fastrlock, cupy-cuda101
  Running setup.py install for fastrlock ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BRADLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fjh34iu0\\fastrlock\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-btkg22tj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: building without Cython
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
    copying fastrlock\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
    copying fastrlock\rlock.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
    copying fastrlock\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
    copying fastrlock\_lock.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastrlock
    running build_ext
    building 'fastrlock.rlock' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\fastrlock
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include" /Tcfastrlock\rlock.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\fastrlock\rlock.obj
    rlock.c
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BRADLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fjh34iu0\\fastrlock\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-btkg22tj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fjh34iu0\fastrlock\

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install torch
Collecting torch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/02/880b468bd382dc79896eaecbeb8ce95e9c4b99a24902874a2cef0b562cea/torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages (from torch) (5.1.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: torch
  Building wheel for torch (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BRADLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qutmjp1k\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-z8jnibmu' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_deps
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qutmjp1k\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
      description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qutmjp1k\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
      from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
  Running setup.py clean for torch
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BRADLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qutmjp1k\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all:
  ERROR: running clean
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
Failed to build torch
Installing collected packages: torch
  Running setup.py install for torch ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BRADLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qutmjp1k\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oq0l1vkx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build_deps
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qutmjp1k\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qutmjp1k\torch\setup.py", line 99, in run
        self.run_command('build_deps')
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qutmjp1k\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BRADLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qutmjp1k\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oq0l1vkx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\BRADLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qutmjp1k\torch\
```

Comment: Have you installed  microsoft visual studio and setuptools? Setuptools are part of MS visual studio. Some libraries need those, even though you are not using MS visual studio as your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Check the official installation for [pytorch on windows](https://pytorch.org/). For e.g to install latest torch version from pip for python3.7 you should run:

```
pip3 install torch===1.4.0 torchvision===0.5.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```